# is it possible to customize click actions under TFS

Tags: svn, tfs

In Svn, if you double click on file that you are checking in, this automatically open the comparison between latest version on server and the file you are about to check-in. In order to do same in TFS, you need to right click and the select appropriate options. Is there anyway to customize action so that I don't have to right click and select rather just double clicking show me the differences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pending Changes window you can use Shift+Enter or Shift+Double click as a shortcut to bring up the compare tool

Comment: definitely better then what i was doing but i still like the way it works with svn